# Remove rows from X_train and y_train at once

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm absolutely new in python, so there is a question.

I've splitted my original df to X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test.
Now i want to drop from y_train (pd.series) outliers therefore i need to remove object with same index from X_train(pd.df).
What is  the easiest and cleanest way to do it?

Comment: Use: `X_train[X_train.index.isin(y_train.index)]` , after u remove outliers from `y_train`

Answer (score 1):

try using `y_train = y_train[X_train_new.index]` where `X_train_new` is your new `X_train` after dropping some columns/row/outliers.